# Error while setting up Docker for gns3

Tags: docker

I want to be able to run docker image in gns3. I installed docker that seems to be working correctly. I then created a new Docker Ubuntu computer on gns3. All went well, but when I try to start docker VM, I get this error:

```
Docker has returned an error: 500 error while creating mount source path '/usr/share/gns3/gns3-server/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gns3server/compute/docker/resources': mkdir /usr/share/gns3: read-only file system
```

I tried some google search with this error. Someone said I should reinstall Docker, and I did. But still having the exact same issue.
Does someone have an idea how to solve this?

thanks

ps:  os is ubuntu 19.04

Answer (score 0):

I know it's too late but I had same issue today and finally find out that it could be solved by removing docker.io and reinstall it

```
sudo apt remove docker docker-engine docker.io 
sudo apt install docker.io
```

PS: another solution that works for me is this:

```
sudo apt remove docker-ce runc
sudo apt install docker-ce
```

After that I restart gns3 and it works fine.